# Connection problems with DHCP solved setting a DHCP client ID. Why?

Tags: dhcp

We are using DHCP in the office and from time to time when I try to connect for first time, my connection is stuck: I get an IP from the DHCP server but the connection doesn't work (I keep the `ping` command running to check that). But "magically" I found this morning that the problem was solved after setting a DHCP client ID in network settings (I'm using Linux Ubuntu). **Why?** I would like to know if it was just a coincidence or not. I used to have this problem in the past and the connection started working after waiting around 5-10 minutes.

I guess this connection problem is caused for some sort of problem identifying clients in the DHCP server (using their MAC I guess), so maybe setting this (optional) DHCP client ID manually is in some way "refreshing" the DHCP server to properly identify my computer?

Hope you can add some clue guys. I'm very curious about that.

Thanks!

Comment: Verify gateway settings and verify that there are no IP conflicts. If you pull the gateway and can't ping it try putting the same settings on another machine and see if it works or not. I've personally had weird experiences where disabling NetworkManager and manually configuring to use DHCP fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me long ago and I think it was something to do with IP release time I made it 24 hours only. Also if there are bridges or wifi extenders don't let them handle the DHCP and forward it to the main router or use AP isloation